# how to prepare dataset to a file for neural network

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

How to combine image and label to a file(dataset) for neural network training, like [mnist](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz) or [imagenet](http://image-net.org/download-imageurls), and how to use tensorflow to read dataset

Comment: dataset comprises of feature vector and corresponding labels there are many feature vector extractor in tensorflow as well as scikit learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you had 3 2x2 images (4 pixels total, 12 total features because pixels have RGB properties) and had 3 possible labels. You could use `one-hot encoding` for the labels, or just assign an integer for each class. Here is some sample code:

```
data = [ [12, 32, 253...4], [155, 32....], [...], [...] #Array of 4 images, each subarray has 12 elements
labels = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

in this case `[12, 32, 253...]` has label `1`, and so on. This is a basic way to organize datasets and labels.

Comment: I am not sure how to make image to [[12, 32, 253...4], ...]

Answer (score 0):

You could use Recurrent neural networks to train the image to get labeled.

Here we input X as images and then train the neural networks to get to learn about the image and correlate with the image. We train with sequence of words and images, the neural network learns by itself. The below two images illustrates the idea.

[We have sequence and sequence out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdP2W.jpg)

[Baby being trained to get labelled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW0YG.jpg)

From these two images you can understand how neural nets can learn